# SQL join arbitrary information to form a mixed list

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, union

I have a list of items of different Types with their respective ID. Items will be grouped together by a group ID:

```
Type  | ID   | GroupID
-----------------------
Type1 | 1234 | 1 
Type1 | 2345 | 1 
Type2 | 1234 | 1 
Type3 | 1234 | 1 
Type1 | 1234 | 2
```

I have separate tables for each Type. The schemas are completely unrelated to one another, therefore `UNION` is not an option:

```
Type1 <id, name, status>
Type2 <id, name, description, foo, bar>
Type3 <id, name, foobar, barfoo, foofoo, hoodeedoo>
```

Is there a way to get all of the data joined in a single list. Over time, we will be adding more types and lists will be loaded on a per group basis. Querying the above data set for **Group 1** would return the following [pseudo] data:

```
[
  { 1234, name, status }, // Type 1
  { 2345, name, status }, // Type 1
  { 1234, name, description, foo, bar }, // Type 2
  { 1234, name, foobar, barfoo, foofoo, hoodeedoo } // Type 3
]
```

#### (update) Purpose of this request:

Our UI will display this list of items. We will have conditional logic to change the behaviors of items clicked. For example, if a Type1 item is clicked, run the behaviors for Type1 - and so on for other types.

Comment: Can you explain the problem you are trying to solve?  I can think of returning strings or XML values, but it really depends on how you're going to use the data, and why you want to put non homogeneous lists in one response.

Comment: Can you work with JSON as a return type?

Comment: I updated the question to describe why we need the data like this. It's not ideal, I know. Might have to go back to the drawing board.

Comment: @joanolo - that's a last ditch solution, which it's looking like might be our only option. I was mostly asking to see if there's some feature of SQL I don't know about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have a result which has a variable structure, your best bet is JSON. The following query would UNION the results of looking at `type_1`, `type_2` and `type_3` and give you the result as JSON:

```
SELECT 
    json_agg(r) AS result
FROM
(
    SELECT row_to_json(t) AS r
       FROM type_1 t
            JOIN item_list il ON il.type='Type1' AND il.id = t.id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT row_to_json(t) AS r
       FROM type_2 t
            JOIN item_list il ON il.type='Type2' AND il.id = t.id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT row_to_json(t) AS r
       FROM type_3 t
            JOIN item_list il ON il.type='Type3' AND il.id = t.id
) AS s0 ;
```

This is what you'd get:

```
|                                            result                                                         |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| [{"id":1234,"name":"name","status":"status"},                                                             |
|  {"id":1234,"name":"name","status":"status"},                                                             |
|  {"id":2345,"name":"name-2","status":"status-2"},                                                         |
|  {"id":1234,"name":"name","description":"description","foo":"foo","bar":"bar"},                           |
|  {"id":1234,"name":"name","foobar":"foobar","barfoo":"barfoo","foofoo":"foofoo","hoodeedoo":"hoodeedoo"}] |
```

You can check it a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/62887/2/0)

---

NOTE: The way the SQL is written does *not* guarantee any ordering. If needed, you should add the appropriate `ORDER BY` before aggregating.

Comment: Awesome - man I love postgres. Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: even with your clarification, I don't know if this is a *good* solution for you, just that it's *a* solution.

You could use string concatenation and `UNION`. It complicates your query nontrivially, but it's certainly possible.

Instead of

```
SELECT * FROM type1
  UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM type2
  UNION ALL
  ...
```

You could do

```
SELECT id, name, status AS info FROM type1
  UNION ALL
SELECT id, name, description || foo || bar AS info FROM type2
  UNION ALL
SELECT id, name, foobar || barfoo || foofoo || hoodeedoo AS info from type3
  ...
```

That returns you table data that looks like:

```
  id  |  name  |            info
------+--------+-----------------------------
 1234 |  name  | status
 2345 |  name  | status
 1234 |  name  | descriptionfoobar
 1234 |  name  | foobarbarfoofoofoohoodeedoo
```

... and so forth.

For readability, you'd probably want to concat some spaces in there. Something like `description || ' ' || foo || ' ' || bar`, or maybe some other sort of separator. SQL string manipulation isn't exactly great, but it's possible, and it might solve this problem for you.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the technique. The `row_to_json` solution is exactly what I needed. This was certainly next best and viable for non-postgres sql stores.